# Did Microsoft break property mapping for font settings in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, visual-studio-2015

Perhaps I am being petty (I think not), but I very much like my IDE set up in a particular way. In VS2012, I had a very particular font set:

[image: Pretty Config]

I have recently upgraded to VS2015 on a different machine, imported my settings from VS2012 and to my disappointment my IDE looks like crap.

> **EDIT**: To be very clear, these colors are VERY different. That is what I concerned with. Don't worry about the resolution of the second image

[image: Ugly Config]

Upon further review, it looks like the `String (C# @ Verbatim)` setting from VS2012 was not implemented in VS2015. Is that the case? If so, its not well documented and leaves me asking: is VS2015 not fully backward compatible?

VS2012 as the config was exported:
[image: Another field example.]

VS2015 as the config was imported:
[image: A different example.]

Manually edited VS2015 property as it should have imported:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your ClearText settings in the Control panel? The colors look the same, it may be that ClearText is screwing with you. Its a bit of a misnomer to me, ClearText, in my eyes, makes text look fuzzy instead of crisper.

Comment: That looks like Clear Type (and [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering)) in the 2nd case. I don't see any `@"verbatim string"` literal used am an unsure why such was drawn out..

Comment: Please focus on the *actual* observed differences, as it will get a better response. If it is clearly a question of fonts being applied then make the different obvious - eg. set the size or color to something clearly distinct. This will also yield a *better* question title as the current title reads very 'aggressive' without backing justification.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. To be very clear, these colors are VERY different. That is what I concerned with. Don't worry about the resolution of the second image - on my screen it is very crisp but also much smaller, i.e. the image was scaled up for this webpage which is why it looks fuzzy (the new machine has a 4k screen vs the old one with lower res).

Comment: The colors look 'much' the same same - at least before possible rendering fuddles - eg. both magenta.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, the string is magenta. It seems like these fields are mapped very poorly. Please focus on all colors - not just the ones that look correct.

Comment: The only thing I can see *definitively* is a rendering difference. **Make the fonts *completely different* to argue a case otherwise.** As it is now it can be explained merely by font rendering differences and not the supposed 'unsupported settings'.

Comment: The post updates keep showing different renderings; which is irrelevant to claim of unsupported settings.

Comment: Added some more screenshots to show a different property where the VS2012 settings were clearly not applied.

Comment: Again, it is not 'clearly' and everything show can be explained due to font rendering differences, including various anti-aliasing methods (arguably making the fonts 'dimmer' and 'softer'). In last two images of font setting selections (for User Types, one from each VS version) the chosen color is also different.

Comment: "In last two images of font setting selections (for User Types, one from each VS version) the chosen color is also different." THAT IS THE POINT! Imported colors != to exported colors. Not sure what you don't understand.

Comment: Regarding the `String (C# @ Verbatim)` setting: in VS2015 it's now called `String - Verbatim`. Perhaps it applies to more languages than C# now (though it doesn't seem to apply to C++ raw string literals)?

Comment: @user1991179 If that's the point you need to change the title of your question. Or maybe just delete it since your problem seems to be trivial and easy to solve. Just the set colours that didn't import correctly to whatever colour you want.

Comment: @RossRidge What other settings did it not import? Its not just about colors...